# ERROR: column "sid" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I tried to create an Enrolment relation using foreign keys in Students(cid) and Courses(cid). Somehow it returns `ERROR:  column "sid" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist` when I run the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE enrollment (                                                                                          
FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Students(sid),                                                                            
FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Courses(cid)                                                                              
);
```

I have checked that both sid and cid exist

```
ALTER table students ADD COLUMN sid int;
```

Returns `ERROR:  column "sid" of relation "students" already exists`

```
university=# ALTER table courses ADD COLUMN cid int;
```

Returns `ERROR:  column "cid" of relation "courses" already exists`

Comment: Your enrollment table does not have a column named `sid` or `cid`

Comment: you're altering the wrong tables, the problem is in "enrollment". The error message does not even mention any other table